# Excel Pivot Table List Duplicate Entries (Not Count Them)

Tags: excel, duplicates, pivot-table

I currently have a table of serial numbers and created a pivot table on another sheet (which contains all my pivot tables for the workbook) to list all the numbers. I know pivot tables are effective at counting how many instances a particular entry is made, but is there a way to list everything even if it is a duplicate?

Example:
Instead of

```
SN  1234    
Count of Entry 2
```

I would like

```
SN 1234 
Count of Entry 1

SN 1234
Count of Entry 1
```

I'm using this pivot table to mirror onto another sheet where there are drop-down menus describing why that number is being evaluated. Any repeats need to have reasons accounted for. If there is a simpler way, please feel free to share.

Edit:

Here is a snippet of the pivot table in question. As you can see, SN 1333 has two instances showing up but has combined it to show the count. I would like it to just show 1333 in two different rows. The second image will reflect every instance of every SN. Hope that clarifies things a little.

[Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMh4A.png)
[Mirror Table on separate tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vazdI.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, could you please show some of your data and how you currently have your pivot table set up.

Comment: Added some extra info. Thanks!